# Using Landsat 7 to go from NDVI to Emissivity

Tags: temperature, landsat

I am using Landsat 7 to calculate land surface derived temperature.
I understand the main concepts behind the conversion, however, I am confused on how to factor Emissivity into my model.
I am using the model builder for my calculations and have created several modules that uses the instruments Gain, Bias Offset, Landsat K1, and Landsat K2 correction variables.
I converted the DN to radiance values as well.

Now, I need to factor in the last and probably the most confusing (for me) part:  Emissivity.
I would like to calculate Emissivity using the NDVI.
I have a model procedure built to calculate the NDVI layer (band4- band3)/(band4+ band3).
I have also calculated Pv, which is the fraction of vegetation calculated by:  [NDVI - NDVI_min]/[NDVI_max-NDVI_min]^2.
Now, by using the Vegetation Cover Method, all I need is Ev and Eg.
I do not understand how to find these values to calculate the Total Emissivity value per cell.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can incorporate the Emissivity into my formulation?
I am slightly confused on how to derive this value...

Comment: Probably better answered by a physics or maths StackExchange site

Answer (score 0):

I believe Emissivity is frequently included as part of the dataset. Alternatively, emissivity databases do exist (such as the ASTER database here: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/about/news_archive/aster_global_emissivity_database_ged_product_release, and others usually maintained by academic departments.)

Values of Ev = 0.99 and Eg = 0.97 are used, and the method of selection discussed, on p. 436 here: ftp://atmosfera.cl/pub/elias/Paula/2004_Sobrino_RSE.pdf (J.A. Sobrino et al. *Land surface temperature retrieval from LANDSAT TM 5*, Remote Sensing of Environment 90, 2004, p. 434–440).

Another approach is taken here: http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2014/01/estimation-of-land-surface-temperature.html

> Estimation of Land Surface Temperature
>   There are several studies about the calculation of land surface temperature. For instance, using NDVI for the estimation of land surface emissivity (Sobrino, et al., 2004), or using a land cover classification for the definition of the land surface emissivity of each class (Weng, et al. 2004).
>
> For instance, the emissivity (e) values of various land cover types are provided in the following table (from Mallick, et al. 2012).
>
> ```
> Soil: 0.928
> Grass: 0.982
> Asphalt: 0.942
> Concrete: 0.937
> ```
>
> Therefore, the land surface temperature can be calculated as (Weng, et al. 2004):
>
> T = TB / [ 1 + (? * TB / ?) lne ]
>   where:
>   ? = wavelength of emitted radiance
>   ? = h * c / s (1.438 * 10^-2 m K)
>   h = Planck’s constant (6.626 * 10^-34 Js)
>   s = Boltzmann constant (1.38 * 10^-23 J/K)
>   c = velocity of light (2.998 * 10^8 m/s)
>
> The values of ? for the thermal bands of Landsat setellites are listed in the following table:
>
> ```
> |      Satellite          | Band | Center wavelength (µm) |
> | Landsat 4, 5, and 7     | 6    | 11.45                  |
> | Landsat 8               | 10   | 10.8                   |
> | Landsat 8               | 11   | 12                     |
> ```

Further reading on emissivity selection, see section 2.3, *Emissivity Retrieval*, here: https://books.google.com/books?id=XN4uAYlexnsC&lpg=PA51&ots=YQrmDa2S1G&dq=vegetation%20and%20bare%20soil%20emissivity&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q&f=false